# TF model scores well but predictions are all over the place

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've been struggling with this for the last week. I'm building an image recognition model with TensorFlow. The model is fairly simple but seems to achieve a reasonable validation and testing accuracy:

```
Epoch 27/30
51/51 [==============================] - 8s 160ms/step - loss: 0.1437 - precision: 0.9443 - recall: 0.9443 - val_loss: 0.1338 - val_precision: 0.9350 - val_recall: 0.9350
Epoch 28/30
51/51 [==============================] - 8s 160ms/step - loss: 0.1612 - precision: 0.9586 - recall: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.1374 - val_precision: 0.9476 - val_recall: 0.9476
Epoch 29/30
51/51 [==============================] - 8s 160ms/step - loss: 0.1500 - precision: 0.9532 - recall: 0.9532 - val_loss: 0.1143 - val_precision: 0.9476 - val_recall: 0.9476
Epoch 30/30
51/51 [==============================] - 8s 160ms/step - loss: 0.1757 - precision: 0.9437 - recall: 0.9437 - val_loss: 0.5685 - val_precision: 0.8889 - val_recall: 0.8889
```

*Note: I'm using precision and recall as metrics since at one stage I thought that accuracy was producing erroneous results.*

The model also achieves a testing accuracy of 91.5%.

The problem comes when I try to classify some images based on this model the classification seems almost random. I even tried putting in some images from training dataset and they are also largely classified incorrectly.

This is how my model is built:

```py
    def create_model(self):

        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                       padding='same', activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        # self.model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))

        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                       padding='same', activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
        
        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                       padding='same', activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
        
        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                       padding='same', activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
        
        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                       padding='same', activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        self.model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))      

         # Dense
        self.model.add(layers.Flatten())
        self.model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
        self.model.add(layers.Dense(self.classes, activation='softmax'))

    def compile_model(self):
        lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
                            initial_learning_rate=1e-2,
                            decay_steps=10000,
                            decay_rate=0.9)
        optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
        los = losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        met = [metrics.Precision(), metrics.Recall()]

        self.model.compile(loss=los,
                           optimizer=optimizer,
                           metrics=met)
    
    def fit_model(self):
        early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss',
                                                          min_delta=0.001,
                                                          patience=20,
                                                          mode='min',
                                                          restore_best_weights=True)
        self.model.fit(self.train, epochs=self.epochs,
                       validation_data=self.val, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

I've tried changing loss functions, playing around with model structure, changing optimizer, etc. but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Now I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong when preparing data for classification. For training I use `ImageDataGenerator()` and its `flow_from_directory()` method. Example of training dataset generation:

```py
        train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                           featurewise_center=True,
                                           rotation_range=30,
                                           width_shift_range=0.2,
                                           height_shift_range=0.2,
                                           horizontal_flip=True)

         self.train = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
             self.source_folder.joinpath('train'),
             target_size=self.target_img_size,
             batch_size=self.batch_size
        )
```

But when making predictions I manually create dataset using OpenCV:

```py
            for f in filenames:
                try:
                    img = cv2.imread(str(f), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    img = cv2.resize(img, self.img_size)
                    img = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
                    img_data.append(img)
                    correct_filenames.append(f)
                except OSError:
                    pass
```

I think something bad happens here that results in predictions being all so random. I classify images one-by-one with the following code:

```py
            for key, value in self.img_dict.items():
                try:
                    value = np.expand_dims(value, axis=0)
                    pr = self.model.predict(value)
                    pred[key] = pr.argmax(axis=-1)
                except (TypeError, ValueError):
                    pass
```

Anyone knows what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Some initial thoughts: Im guessing you aren't actually using the model you trained. Im wondering if your weights aren't being saved or if you are assigning a brand new model object (with new random weights / biases) and running your individual tests on that.

Comment: I'm saving and then loading saved model, I just didn't want to include this part as the post is already over-full with code. @GunnerStone

Comment: Check the class distribution. Increase the datasets size.I see you are already augmenting some data. Train for more epochs.

Comment: @ArunSg, I made sure that with the current model both of my classes are of approximately equal size and I'm training for so few epochs since model already produces sufficient accuracy to test results and I've trained for ~200 epochs at earlier stages, but results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

This line when loading images is a minmax scale to [0, 1].

```
img = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```

During training you rescale your data by dividing with 255 (which is probably fine) but there's also this argument featurewise_center=True, which according to tensorflow subtracts the mean from the dataset featurewise [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator].

I don't know how long training takes but you should either train a model with this being False, or calculate the feature-wise mean for every feature in the set you used for training and then, subtract this mean for every feature of your test images.

So the problematic line might be this one

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, featurewise_center=True, rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
```

To test if this is the issue causing these errors, train something small really quick and get back to us.

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't seem to help. The other issue I noticed in the training output in the beginning is that at each step precision and recall are *exactly the same* but this is should not be happening especially considering I have slightly different sizes of original classes - one class has 980 images and the other - 1120 so it seems that something very strange is happening here.

Comment: Also, you're using cross entropy with the from_logits argument being True AND use softmax as an activation function in the end. It's not the thing causing the problem, but perhaps you'd like to switch to from_logits = False. - Edid: Wow what's that spike in val_loss in epoch 30? Also, 8 seconds per epoch for image data? Very impressive.

Comment: Yeah, it's a very odd spike in epoch 30, probably need to train for longer but I did that before and it didn't help. With the time per epoch, I downscale images to 256*256 and also have an RTX3060 even though it's only a laptop version.